# How to populate a list with items.count() from a queryset sorted by a datetime field

Tags: python, django, pygooglechart

I had a hard time formulating the title, so please edit it if you have a better one :)

I'm trying to display some statistics using the pygooglechart. And I am using Django to get the database items out of the database.

The database items has a datetime field wich i want to "sort on". What i really want is to populate a list like this.

```
data = [10, 12, 51, 50]
```

Where each list item is the number(count) of database items within an hour. So lets say i do a query that gets all items in the last 72 hours, i want to collect the count of each hour into a list item. Anybody have a good way to do this?

Comment: why did you make this a community wiki? it should be a regular question imo

Comment: There are no rules and what can and cannot be a community wiki. If you want to make it a wiki (for **whatever** reason), you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running Django 1.1 or a fairly recent checkout, you can use the new [aggregation features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/). Something like:

```
counts = MyModel.objects.values('datettimefield').annotate(Count('datettimefield'))
```

This actually gets you a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'datetimefield':<date1>, 'datettimefield__count':<count1>},
 {'datetimefield':<date2>, 'datettimefield__count':<count2>}, ...]
```

but it should be fairly easy to write a list comprehension to get the format you want.

**Edited after comment**: If you're on 1.0.2, the most efficient thing to do is to fall back to raw SQL.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
     "SELECT COUNT(0) FROM `mymodel_table` "
     "GROUP BY `mydatetimefield`;"
)
counts = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Sadly I am running 1.0.2 on this project, any pointers on the list comprehension? I cant seem to get i working in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

[django aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)